# What Font is This? Is It Possible to Replicate Using \textgreek and PDFlatex?

Tags: pdftex, typography, greek

In my various projects, I occasionally encounter some Greek that I would like to typeset as close to the original as possible.

For example,

[image]

I have tried to mimic this using `\textgreek`. Consider the MWE

```
 \documentclass{book}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand{\textgreek}[1]{\begingroup\fontencoding{LGR}\selectfont#1\endgroup}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\Huge

\textbf{(\textit{\textgreek{jus'ia `ilasmo{\!\t{\!n}}}})}
\end{document
```

It produces the following output:

[image]

As you can see, it is not a perfect rendition. For instance, the leading theta in the first word does not match the original; and, I am not sure the accent on the leading iota of the second word is correct. With some attempts, I have been able to get the two alphas to resemble a lower case `a'; but overall, the appearance of the two words does not come close to the original.

QUESTION: Can someone show me how to render the typesetting as close to the original as possible? I run the code with PDFLatex as this is what the larger document is using---so something else would not be helpful in this case.

Thank you.

Comment: why did you delete your previous question and ignored my comment there?

Comment: You should check [the Greek Font Society](https://greekfontsociety-gfs.gr/typefaces) and the [list of Greek fonts on CTAN.](https://www.ctan.org/topic/font-greek)

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer If I remember correctly, your comment asked for the two words to be typed (not photocopied); I figured I would make a better attempt at typesetting the two words as best as I am able. Hence, the deletion of the old and and revision now asking basically different questions. I hope this question is more satisfactory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like [GFS Porson](https://www.greekfontsociety-gfs.gr/typefaces/19th_century)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[greek.polutoniko,english]{babel}

\DeclareFontFamilySubstitution{LGR}{\familydefault}{porson}

\begin{document}

\textgreek{jus'ia <ilasmo\~u}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also use direct Greek input:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[greek.polutoniko,english]{babel}

\DeclareFontFamilySubstitution{LGR}{\familydefault}{porson}

\begin{document}

\textgreek{jus'ia <ilasmo\~u}

\textgreek{θυσία ἱλασμοῦ}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The output is very nice. However, when I try to run the code, I get the following error---  Package babel Error: Language definition file greek.polutoniko.ldf not found.  And so it indicates an Undefined Control Sequence for \DeclareFontFamily Substitution. Can you suggest what may be the problem?---I am sure it is on my end. Thank you.

Comment: Just a small correction: the accent is not correct, `<` should be used.

Comment: @nplatis Where should < be used? in place of >?

Comment: @nplatis You're right! I'll fix.

Comment: @mlchristians You seem to have a rather old TeX distribution.

Comment: @egreg Thank you. That is probably where the problem lies.